# Idiom like "His star is shining"

Tags: idioms

There's an idiom that's on the tip of my tongue, but I don't remember what it is. I remember it as "His star is shining" but I'm not sure that's it, I may be confusing it with something else. it's supposed to mean that he's having a good period or he's reigning, and everyone is adoring him. Does that sound familiar to anyone?

Comment: here's an Eagles song about someone who's a rising star ... http://en.musicplayon.com/play?v=546606

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re probably thinking of

> His star is rising.

Or:

> He’s a rising star in X.

Comment: Or possibly *His star is in the ascendant*.

Comment: @StoneyB Yes, I thought of that one too, but I was trying to avoid astrology. :)

Answer (score 1):

You may be referring to the expression :

> to be [the shining star](http://www.dhakatribune.com/career/2014/may/06/be-shining-star-your-workplace), that is to be the most promising or attractive person in a specific context.